# Custom endpoint to retrieve comments from posts if user is not logged in: not working

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest

Situation:

1. WordPress by default does not allow access to comments of a post via REST API if user is not logged in
2. I tried by passing this by creating a custom endpoint
3. Custom endpoint shows a list of all comments with associated post IDs

Problem:
I can't access a specific comment for a certain post ID (or a list of all the comments for let's say post ID = 5.

How can I fix this?

My code in functions.php:

```
function custom_get_comments_by_post_id($request) {
    $post_id = $request->get_param('id'); // Retrieve the post ID from the request parameter

    global $wpdb;

    $comments = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_post_ID = %d AND comment_approved = 1",
            $post_id
        )
    );

    if (empty($comments)) {
        return new WP_REST_Response(array(), 200); // Return an empty array if no comments found
    }

    return new WP_REST_Response($comments, 200);
}

function register_custom_endpoints() {
    register_rest_route('custom/v1', '/post-comments/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'custom_get_comments_by_post_id',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true', // Allow access to all users
    ));
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_custom_endpoints');
```